# После добавление контента с помощью PHP кода контент из head перемещается в body

Tags: php, html

Возникла некая проблема, если на страницу с помощью echo из `php` кода добавляется какой-то контент то всё что было в `head` перемещается в `body`, и естественно становится не работающим.

Вот пример: 
До `echo`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
  <title>Автризируйтесь, пожалуйста </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>LOG IN</h1>
    <h3>USE YOUR ACCOUNT </h3>
    <h5>Login</h5>
    <form method="POST">
      <input type="login" name="login" spellcheck="false" required="">
      <h5>Password</h5>
      <input type="password" name="pass" required="">
      <input type="submit" name="b_login" value="LOG IN" id="login">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

После `echo`:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="error" style="top:0px; height:auto; ">
    <p>You account banned until 2519-07-16 08:50:52 GMT Reason: Тест</p>
  </div>

  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
  <title>Автризируйтесь, пожалуйста </title>


  <div class="login">
    <h1>LOG IN</h1>
    <h3>USE YOUR ACCOUNT </h3>
    <h5>Login</h5>
    <form method="POST">
      <input type="login" name="login" spellcheck="false" required="">
      <h5>Password</h5>
      <input type="password" name="pass" required="">
      <input type="submit" name="b_login" value="LOG IN" id="login">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Исходники `login.php`

```
<?php 
    require "includes/db.php";
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
        header("Location: profile.php");}
    if (isset($_POST["b_login"])){
        $user = R::findOne("users", 'login = ?', array($_POST["login"]));
        if ($user) {
            if (password_verify($_POST["pass"], $user->password)){ 
                if ($user->banned>time()){
                    $errors[]= "You account banned until ".gmdate("Y-m-d\ H:i:s", $user->banned)." GMT";
                    if (!empty($user->ban_reason)){
                        $errors[0] = $errors[0]." Reason: ".$user->ban_reason;
                    }
                } else {
                    $user->agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    $user->last_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    $user->last_visit = time();
                    R::store($user);
                    $_SESSION["logged"] = array($user->id, $user->login, $user->join, $user->admin, $user->last_visit, $user->avatar);
                    header("Location: profile.php");
                }
            } else {
                $errors[] = "Wrong password";
            }
        } else {
            $errors[]= "User with this login was not found.";
        }
    if (!empty($errors)){
        echo "<div class=\"error\" style=\"top:0px; height:auto; \"> <p>".$errors[0]."</p> </div>";
    }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <title>Автризируйтесь, пожалуйста </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <h1>LOG IN</h1>
        <h3>USE YOUR ACCOUNT </h3>
        <h5>Login</h5>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="login" name="login" spellcheck="false" required>
            <h5>Password</h5>
            <input type="password" name="pass" required>
            <input type="submit" name="b_login" value="LOG IN" id="login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ну вот у вас див выводится раньше открывающего `<html>`.

Comment: Как его вывести в <html>?

Comment: Переместить свой код? Переместить `echo` куда надо?

Comment: В начало  `<body>`

Comment: Ну в итоге проблема в чем?

Comment: Проблема в том что всё что было в `<head> </head>` каким-то образом перемещается в `<body> </body>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <div class="error" style="top:0px; height:auto; ">
>   <p>You account banned until 2519-07-16 08:50:52 GMT Reason: Тест</p>
> </div>
> ```

В соответствии с правилами парсинга html-страницы браузер когда встречает тег `<div>` (либо любой другой тег, которому не место в head), он немедленно закрывает `head` и открывает `body`.

Перемести вывод этого сообщения так, чтобы оно находилось в body.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="login">
<?php   
// Вывод ошибок перенести сюда
if (!empty($errors)){
    echo "<div class=\"error\" style=\"top:0px; height:auto; \"> <p>".$errors[0]."</p> </div>";
}?>
    <h1>LOG IN</h1>
    <h3>USE YOUR ACCOUNT </h3>
    <h5>Login</h5>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="login" name="login" spellcheck="false" required>
        <h5>Password</h5>
        <input type="password" name="pass" required>
        <input type="submit" name="b_login" value="LOG IN" id="login">
    </form>
</div>
```